# Additional marker information Google Maps Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I'm creating Google Maps API based app for android and I need to add some additional information to `Marker` like my own rating of the place, comments, photos etc. I've tried to create new class, extended from `Marker.class`, but I can't because `Marker.class`is final. How to add additional information?

Comment: You can go with this official document for custom marker.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Comment: Thanks, I used 'setTag()', but can I create custom marker another way? Because it's means, that I can pass only id or smth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `marker.setTag()` when you're creating the marker with key to info associated with that marker....you can then access this (by calling `getTag()`) in `OnInfoWindowClickListener` callback for example and use that to look up info you need.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this, but can I create custom marker another way? Or this is the only solution?